# Setting function with setInterval() to act at some value

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, while-loop, setinterval

I've created `start()` function which counts from 1 onwards.

I want it to do something after some time pass, for example 5 seconds.

How to achieve that?

I've tried with **`if (timecounter == 5)`** but that doesn't work.

If I put **`while (timecounter < 5) {continue}`** and then the **`if`** statement from above, **I get into infinite loop**.

```
function start() {
    setInterval(function () {
        timecounter = timecounter + 1;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = timecounter;
    }, 1000);

    var clickArea = document.getElementById('clickBox');

    document.getElementById('boxText').style.color = 'white';

    clickArea.addEventListener("click", function () {
        counter += 1;
    });

    if (timecounter === 5) {
        alert('this');
    } //Doesn't work

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a setTimeout()?

Comment: `if (timecounter === 5) {` will always be false because you set the `timecounter` inside your `setInterval`. The rest of the function will only be triggered once.

Comment: It needs to be in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a few people mentioned in the comments; your test needs to be called whenever timecounter is incremented. http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/bsAfp/

```
function start() {
  var timecounter = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    timecounter = timecounter + 1;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = timecounter;
    if (timecounter === 5){
      alert('this');
    } //works now
  }, 1000);
}
start();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look below, the callback function for `setInterval` is where you can add your checks. That callback function is called every interval time, which you set to `1000`

```
function start() {
    setInterval(function () {
        timecounter = timecounter + 1;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = timecounter;

        // this function will be the function that is getting called every second.
        // here you can put in your checks for 5 seconds.

        if (timecounter === 5) {
            // do something
        }
    }, 1000);

    var clickArea = document.getElementById('clickBox');

    document.getElementById('boxText').style.color = 'white';

    clickArea.addEventListener("click", function () {
        counter += 1;
    });
}
```